# Insert row into table that has FK obtained from another table - linq -c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 tables, Clients and ClientInterests. The PK/FK being ClientID of type GUID

This is my Linq, where I want to insert into the ClientIneterests table

```
    ClientInterestRegistration clientRegisteration = new ClientInterestRegistration
{
    ClientID = (from v in DB.Clients
                where v.Email.Equals(EmailAddress)
                select new {v.ClientID}).Single(), 

    ClientInterest = SelectedInterests,
    ..
};
```

Error received is:
Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>` to `System.Guid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, consider removing `new {...}` from the query and changing it to:

```
ClientID = (from v in DB.Clients
            where v.Email.Equals(EmailAddress)
            select v.ClientID).Single()
```

What you are doing is to create a new structure with the `ClientID` as its property.

However, you shouldn't work directly with the key column at all. Try setting the `Client` directly to the object:

```
Client = (from v in DB.Clients
          where v.Email.Equals(EmailAddress)
          select v).Single()
```

Comment: Mehrdad: You solution,
ClientID = (from v in DB.Clients
            where v.Email.Equals(EmailAddress)
            select v.ClientID).Single()

Worked.